# Javascript variables as parameters for tcl

Tags: javascript, html, tcl

I'm running a TclHttp Server and I want to pass some java script variables into a tcl function call inside an .tml file.

somewhat like this:

```
<html>
...
<script>

var myString = document.title;

var result = [myNamespace::myFunction myString]

</script>
...
</html>
```

Is this possible? I tried to convert the whole command to a string and call it with eval() or as function and I tried to use ncgi::value and "",[],$  but nothing worked.

Comment: No it is not possible. Not without a complex RPC structure. (And even then you'll have to decide what side is the master (You could either have the client call your function on the server, or let the server call the function on the client). Ohh, and then there is the security thing. If you let the client call `exec` on the server, it is over.

Comment: What would be the part that needs an RPC structure?
Calling the function or passing the parameters?
Because calling the function already works thanks to the tcl server.

Comment: Calling the function when the client needs the result of the function while passing the client side values. (You can not call your function until `var mystring = ...` has been executed. But you can't evaluate the script because your function has to be evaluated before `var result = ...`. Chicken/Egg problem. The only solution is to use some kind of RPC to call your function on the server (and passing the myString value) when the value of myString is known on the client side. RPC stuff usually involves AJAX, but then waiting for the result is impossible in JS. Tcl has coroutines, JS not.

Comment: @Johannes That's the sort of thing that a safe interpreter (associated with the session?) is for.

Comment: @DonalFellows Sure. But even a safe interp can bring your single threaded application to an halt with an instruction like `if {(1<3000000)eq""} {}`

Comment: @Johannes That's very hard to avoid, and is why you should generally avoid evaluating untrusted code anyway. Going to multiple threads and adding time limits will make things easier, but that really needs wrapping up. Also, tclhttpd doesn't have this level of complexity…

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of passing values back and forth is by getting the JS to POST a JSON document to the Tcl code which then computes the result and sends a JSON document back. There are multiple libraries for JS that can handle its side of things (I've got some experience with using jQuery for this sort of thing) and on the Tcl side, Tcllib's [json](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html) and [json::write](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json_write.html) look to be the very thing.

Comment: How would I post a JSON document to the tcl code? I read your links but I don't really get it from the litte snippet. A complete example even if small with one JS/HTML file and one tcl file would be much appreciated.